# Edit item within views in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

There is some problem, I'm trying to update the product on the client by making changes and clicking on the update button - my page is refreshing w/o updating info, so the product has the same data as before. But in the logs, the status code of the GET request is 200 and shows the updated object in the database. When I try to update through the admin Django dashboard, everything works successfully, the problem is only on the client side of the web application. What issues can there be?
Thank you in advance!

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
CATEGORY = (
    ('Stationary', 'Stationary'),
    ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
    ('Food', 'Food'),
)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    order_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer}-{self.name}'
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='user-login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['Admin'])
def product_edit(request, pk):
    item = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard-products')
    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=item)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/products_edit.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

html template:

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Products Edit Page{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row my-4">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 p-3 bg-white">
        <h3>Edit Item</h3>
        <hr>
        <form>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Confirm">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: could you share your forms.py and models.py for the Product ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow of course, added

Comment: Is it a client cache issue? Does reloading the page update what you see? Clearing the browser cache and then reloading the page?

Comment: @nigel222 I tried, nothing happens. The data also does not change in the database when using the form. But with the help of django dashboard - works fine.

Comment: @nigel222 got this in url address line in browser "127.0.0.1:8000/products/edit/10/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=vpUS3NBcqi75tOYE1VCDzevjN2U24czKq4LNjccKWhREPHj2GIKSos6Mel4p9f1b&name=Book&quantity=130&category=Electronics"

Comment: what you template(dashboard/products_edit.html) looks like could you share it ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to pass `POST` method you are using `GET`.

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Products Edit Page{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row my-4">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 p-3 bg-white">
        <h3>Edit Item</h3>
        <hr>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Confirm">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```